# Lazy Singleton with property that references parent in constructor

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

I have a Singleton which functions as a context object for a web application. This Singleton follows Jon Skeets excellent [Lazy Singleton model](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

The end result, is a `Context.Current` object which serves as a reference point for many functions.

The problem I'm running into is with a Property of this object which is a class called `Providers`. It gives me OAuth information like ClientId about a series of cloud providers.

ClientIds change based on your endpoint for most providers, so in the Constructor for each Provider, I check ... you guessed it, `Context.Current.DeploymentType` which is an `ENUM` that tells me which environment I'm in.

Calling an object during it's instantiate is quite bad form, and I end up with a:

`ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.`

Now, I could simply not reference `Context.Current.DeploymentType` in the constructor for `Provider`, and just do the same work that the `ENUM` does when it instantiates over and over again, but it feels inefficient.

I could create the `ENUM` separately, and then again for the `Context.Current`, but that feels wrong as well.

My current code is:

```
public Providers AllProviders = Providers.Instance;
```

Is there a way to say:

```
public Providers AllProviders {get; don't instantiate me until someone calls me}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not uncommon in Singleton pattern. The object being initialized needs to access a property from the singleton, which is not yet initialized. Typically, the way to address that is to lazy initialize other instances and properties to avoid this issue.

In your example, the property is initialized during object construction because of its declaration. In order to avoid it from being initialized during the object construction, you could do this:

```
public Providers AllProviders
{
    get
    {
        if (this.allProviders == null) this.allProviders = Providers.Instance; // alternatively, do what Providers.Instance is actually doing
        return this.allProviders;
    }
}
```

Looks like that should solve this issue, if I have understood it correctly. By making this change, during construction, the property is not initialized and Providers.Instance is not called. It is only called (and then cached) when AllProviders is accessed.

It is, of course, not thread-safe (unless the Providers.Instance is already thread-safe) and you may have to do some work to make it thread-safe, which is going to happen with the approach you have proposed (i.e. "do not instantiate me until someone calls me").

Comment: FYI: You may also not need to have this.allProviders field if Providers.Instance already handles the case of not initializing if an initialization has already been done. Ideally, that's how it should be but I had included the this.allProviders field because I do not know what's in Providers.Instance.